# Get unusual colnanme in data.frame

Tags: r

Here is my code,

```
x<-c(70, 82, 91, 76, 84, 94, 72, 76, 74, 67, 70, 45, 69, 86, 75,
    84, 63, 93, 87, 67, 71, 83, 90, 88, 58, 69, 91, 74, 80, 79,  
    75, 88, 87, 50, 80, 84, 94, 72, 85, 71, 81, 74, 75, 81, 75, 57,
    78, 78, 61, 60)                 
y<-table(cut(x, breaks=c(0,60,70,80,90,100),include.lowest=TRUE,right=FALSE)) 
z<-cbind(y,prop=prop.table(y)*100)  
z
```

i can get the table:

```
          y prop  
[0,60)    4    8  
[60,70)   7   14  
[70,80)  18   36  
[80,90)  15   30  
[90,100]  6   12
```

if i want to get the table such as

```
          y prop%  
[0,60)    4    8
[60,70)   7   14
[70,80)  18   36
[80,90)  15   30
[90,100]  6   12
```

how can i do?

Comment: Column names are strings. R has methods of string manipulation (as clumsy as they are). What's the problem?

Comment: i get it :z<-cbind(y,"prop(%)"=prop.table(y)*100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colnames` to accomplish what you would like.  Make sure to have your new names inside of `c()`

```
colnames(z) <- c("y", "prop%")
z


          y prop%
[0,60)    4     8
[60,70)   7    14
[70,80)  18    36
[80,90)  15    30
[90,100]  6    12
```